# Excel VBA: Create shapes hierarchy from list

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through an "ordered" list to create several rectangle shapes in hierarchy style (and link them with elbow connectors). Example: on my WBSdata sheet, I have the following

```
     A              B
1    0.        Box 0. lvl1
2    0.1.      Box 0.1. lvl2
3              Comment 1
4              Comment 2
5    0.1.1.    Box 0.1.1. lvl3
6              Comment 1
7              Comment 2
8              Comment 3
9    0.2.      Box 0.2. lvl2
10   0.2.1.    Box 0.2.1. lvl3
11   0.2.2.    Box O.2.1. lvl3
12             Comment 1
13             Comment 2
14   1.        Box 1. lvl1
15             Comment 1
16             Comment 2
17   1.1.      Box 1.1. lvl2
```

Would output something like this on the WBS sheet:
[image: Hierarchy]

Basically, read the "index" in column A, if it's first level (2 characters in column A), draw a blue box and write the corresponding value from column B, then look at the line below, if it's a level 2 box (4 characters), draw it below (a bit shorter on the left side), assign it the value ; same for lvl 3 box. If column A i empty, create a text box below the shape, and add all the comments.

So far (see code below), I managed to create a box (yay), style it and add the text, as well as create a text box (with a line on the side, like in the picture, but i'd need it to be the same "dynamic" height as the text box), but i can't get it to add all the comments. I can't get the magic to understand that it needs to move to the next "level" (go from blue box to green box for example).

I haven't yet tried to connect each box to its "hierarchical superior", but that's another story :)

I'm pretty sure i'm not managing my variables correctly (mainly the counter), making it reset at the right time, etc...

Any tips to send me on the right direction?

```
Public Sub wbsShape()


Dim wbs, wbsdata As Worksheet
Set wbs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WBS")
Set wbsdata = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WBSdata")

i = 2 'counter, because data starts on line 2
ileft = 100 'initial position from left of sheet
itop = 100 'initial position from top of sheet
lg = 175 'main box width
ht = 50 'main box height
ind = 10 'indent (for lines, or smaller boxes)
impred = RGB(128, 0, 0) 'red
impgreen = RGB(0, 128, 0) 'green
impblue = RGB(0, 0, 128) 'blue
impgrey = RGB(200, 200, 200) 'light grey for border
black = RGB(0, 0, 0)
white = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Do While Not IsEmpty(wbsdata.Cells(i, "A").Value)

With wbs.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ileft, itop, lg, ht)
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = impblue
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = impgrey
    .Line.Weight = 1
    .Name = wbsdata.Cells(i, "B").Value
    With .TextFrame
            With .Characters
                    .Text = UCase(wbsdata.Cells(i, "B").Value)
                    With .Font
                            .Color = white
                            .Name = "Arial"
                            .Size = 14
                            .FontStyle = "Bold"
                    End With
            End With
                 .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                 .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
      End With

   End With

i = i + 1

    If IsEmpty(wbsdata.Cells(i, "A").Value) Then
    wbs.Shapes.AddLine(ileft + ind, itop + ht, ileft + ind, itop + ht + 100).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 10)
        With wbs.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, ileft + 2 * ind, itop + ht, lg - ind, 30)
             .Line.Visible = msoFalse
             .Fill.Transparency = 1
            With .TextFrame.Characters
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Text = wbsdata.Cells(i, "B").Value
            End With
    End With

End If

itop = itop + ht + 20

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Not exactly sure where you are stuck. If the colour depends on the length of column A use len or use Split to find the number of dots and base the colour etc on that. Assign the boxes to variables and then you can refer to them in later code or write a function with some parameters to do the drawing.

Comment: Tbh though, not sure if Excel is the best tool for this!

Comment: @SJR Or at least use the "Smart Art" tool available in Office - it's designed for this kind of graphic.

Comment: @CindyMeister - good point, it even has a Heirarchy category.

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, the hierarchy SmartShape has limited "functionality"... Can I rephrase my question then? how would you go about saying (in vba) : "hey, read A1, draw the rectangle with the text inside, then read A2: if it has more characters, make another rectangle 1 "lvl" lower, if it is empty, create a text box below the initial rectangle". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to be a lot of work (I've stripped out a lot of your formatting), but perhaps this will start you off in the right direction.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, v, s As Shape
ileft = 100 'initial position from left of sheet
itop = 100 'initial position from top of sheet
lg = 175 'main box width
ht = 50 'main box height
ind = 10 'indent (for lines, or smaller boxes)
impred = RGB(128, 0, 0) 'red
impgreen = RGB(0, 128, 0) 'green
impblue = RGB(0, 0, 128) 'blue
impgrey = RGB(200, 200, 200) 'light grey for border
black = RGB(0, 0, 0)
white = RGB(255, 255, 255)

For Each r In Range("A1:A4")
    v = Split(r, ".")
    If UBound(v) = 1 Then
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ileft, itop, lg, ht)
        s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = impblue
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = r.Offset(, 1)
        itop = itop + 75
    ElseIf UBound(v) = 2 Then
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ileft, itop, lg, ht)
        s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = impgreen
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = r.Offset(, 1)
        itop = itop + 75
    ElseIf r = vbNullString Then
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, ileft + 2 * ind, itop + ht, lg - ind, 30)
        s.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        s.Fill.Transparency = 1
        With s.TextFrame.Characters
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Text = r.Offset(, 1).Value
        End With
        itop = itop + 75
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```